# Add flag in developer console

Tags: javascript, webdriver-io, wdio

I am writing automation framework using wdio. I want to add the below line in developer console. This flag basically enables a functionality in the web app. How can I do it?

Flag to be added : DEBUG.setBrowserFlag('flag-name',true)

I tried below things but it did not work:

```
   await browser.executeAsync(function(flag, done) {
        // Access the `window` object in the browser's context
        var browserWindow = window || {};
      
        // Add the flag to the `window` object
        browserWindow.myFlag = flag;
      
        // Indicate that the execution is complete
        done();
      }, '--DEBUG.setBrowserFlag(\'hz_pjx_em0_access\',true)');
```

.

```
const consoleElement = await $('input.js-console-widget-input');

    // Type 'hello' in the console
    await consoleElement.setValue("DEBUG.setBrowserFlag('hz_pjx_em0_access',true);");

    // Press Enter key
    await browser.keys(['Enter']);
```